# Remove an HTTP Request PATH Variable if null

Tags: jmeter

I have this script in JMeter, PUT method,
how can i remove a path variable if the value from the input data is blank?

I know i can remove this if the parameter were in the Parameter tab of the HTTP request using the remove Arguments, the thing is I have a value in the body data so I have to put the URL parameters in the path that's why remove arguments is not working anymore.

code:

```
if ("${thisfromCSV}" == "") {
    sampler.getArguments().removeArgument("thisParameter");
}
```

this works if the parameter is located at the Parameters tab of the HTTP Request

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please post your code attempt so others can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Add [JSR223 PreProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor) as a child of the [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) you would like to modify
2. Put the following code into "Script" area:

   ```
   def url = new URL("http://example.com" + sampler.getPath())

   def params = url.query.split('&').collectEntries({ param ->
       param.split('=').collect {
           URLDecoder.decode(it, 'UTF-8')
       }
   })

   if (vars.get('thisfromCSV') == '') {
       params.remove('thisParameter')
   }

   def query = params.collect { k, v -> "$k=$v" }.join('&')

   sampler.setPath(url.path + '?' + query)
   ```
3. That's it, the code will remove `thisParameter` from the Sampler's URL query string in case of `thisfromCSV` variable is empty.

See [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) for more information on using Groovy scripting in JMeter tests.